# How to determine the coordinate of the tabBar in SwiftUi in order to position a slide-over card right above it

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I am using the [following source code](https://github.com/moifort/swiftUI-slide-over-card/blob/master/Sources/SlideOverCard/SlideOverCard.swift) for building an slide-over card in my SwiftUi app. The card position is defined by the following code section:

```
public enum CardPosition: CGFloat {
    
    case bottom , middle, top
    
    func offsetFromTop() -> CGFloat {
        switch self {
        case .bottom:
            return UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 80
        case .middle:
            return UIScreen.main.bounds.height/1.8
        case .top:
            return 80
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change the *bottom position* in such a way that the card always lies right above the tabBar [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwjA4.png), no matter which screen size it is used on.
I have tried many many variants for example `case .bottom: return UIScreen.main.bounds.height - UITabBarController().tabBar.frame.size.height` or `UIApplication.shared.windows[0].safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.maxY - UITabBarController().tabBar.frame.size.height` but still without any success.

The code template which I am using is the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    // for SlideOverCard
    @State private var position = CardPosition.bottom
    @State private var background = BackgroundStyle.blur
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                ZStack(alignment: Alignment.top){
                    List() { Text("Elements") }
                    
                    SlideOverCard($position, backgroundStyle: $background) {
                        Form{Text("Some content")}
                    }
                    
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("List"))
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                Text("Tab")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Is there any idea how I can get the coordinate of the place right above the tabBar?

Answer (score 0):

I use this in SceneDelegate to get the bottom safe area size, that you cann add to the TabView height, it's gonna give you the "real" height between the bottom of your screen and the top of your TabView.

```
let safeAreaInsets = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

Let me know if something is unclear.

Cheers

Comment: After using your code e.g. on iPhone 11 the (bottom)safeAreaInsets has the value of 34. By setting `case .bottom: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - bottomSafeAreaInsets!` the card is still **far** bellow the screen (an offset  of -200 makes it exactly on the tabView border). Thus, unfortunately the problem is still not solved.

Comment: Minus the TabView height too ? 
case .bottom: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - bottomSafeAreaInsets! - 80

Comment: No help. Somehow `case .bottom: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - bottomSafeAreaInsets! - 200` would work for iPhone 11. But this is not the idea. Because in other iPhones the offset differs and the card will be shifted from the wished position. Even `UIScreen.main.bounds.height - bottomSafeAreaInsets! - UITabBarController().tabBar.frame.size.height` doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

get the tabbar top y ... then subtract your view height .. that is the your y coordinate ... you have to do that on viewDidAppear , after tabbar layout get done